# JProfiler GUI on local windows machine can't connect to remote Linux server machine

Tags: jprofiler

1) I ran my server program on a linux machine, remotely.

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 41
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...
```

2) I then try to connect my profiler GUI from my local windows machine.  I got the config.xml from the server generated by JProfiler and imported it via the GUI.  When I try to connect, I  get a "Connection status" in progress forever.

i am able to telnet to the Linux machine to the specific port, 8849.

Interestingly, when i kill the server on the Linux machine, the "Connection status" dialog box on my GUI is also killed.  And it shows this message.
"Either an old version of the native library is used or another application is listening on port 8849.  Please check your PATH environment variable and your port configuration".

Answer (score 1):

I've found out my issue.  My client side has version 8.07 while my server side has version 8.10.  After I upgrade my client side, everything works.